# Доступ к соседним структурам в vector при итерации по нему. С++

Tags: c++, vector, stl

У меня есть `vector asp` структур. В цикле итерации по `vector` для вычислений мне необходимо получить значения предыдущей `asp` структуры и последующей `asp` структуры.

```
for (asp& a_asp : aspectFile){
   asp previos = ???; //предыдущая структура
   asp actual = a_asp; // актуальное значение
   a_asp next = ???; //последующая структура
    }
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: Сделайте итерацию через индекс (классический for), и обращайтесь через `[i-1]`, `[i+1]`. Не забыв, конечно, про границы.

Comment: А можно немного схитрить, чтобы избежать проверок при каждой итерации: итерироваться с 3-его элемента до конца списка, при этом записывая в две переменные указатели на предыдущий и пред-предыдущий элементы.

Comment: Я уже думал над этим чтобы пустить 2 итерации одна из которой будет бежать впереди другой. Но это ненормально.

Comment: Я  схитрил делая итерацию и запоминая значения затем произвожу вычисления и сохраняюсь в другой vector, Потому что сохранять нужно всегда в среднем элементе. Хотелось бы узнать как правильно и эффективно это сделать. Вектора огромные.